# Angular, is nesting Observables needed when partially optional?

Tags: angular, observable

I am somewhat new to Angular and am finally confused about the correct usage of Observables. I can't even formulate a concrete question, so I have to do it in a roundabout way.

**tl;dr:** I think the question boils down to: How can I syncronize requests that depend each other, but only if needed? Is lazy-loading prerequisites(which probably are Observables) before doing a task just bad practice, and should i load every possible prerequisite on appstart instead?

**/tl:dr**

The story:
For an autocompleting Input-Field I want to use an API for the suggestions. I don't know the URI yet, I have to request an ApiConfig first, which tells me the URI.

So I want to request the config once, and multiple times the suggestions.

This is what I have now, but I don't like, that I have to call `getSearchModuleUri()` each time and the request for suggestions is in it's subscribe-body. In my mind it's not right hierachically, because the uri is in the focus way more than the actual crucial GET-request.

```
    getSuggestions: Observable<SearchResult[]>(searchTerm: string) {
        return this.getSearchModuleUri().subscribe(searchUri => this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(searchUri));
    }

    getSearchModuleUri(): Observable<string> {
        //magical stuff - equal to Observable.of('http://host/api/foo')
        return uriAsObservable();
    }
}
```

I'd rather have a class variable that holds the searchUri once I retrieved it:

```
    searchUri: string;

    getSuggestions: Observable<SearchResult[]>(searchTerm: string) {
        this.getSearchModuleUri();
        return this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(searchUri));
    }

    getSearchModuleUri(): Observable<string> {
        //still magical stuff - equal to Observable.of('http://host/api/foo')
        if(searchUri){
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            //get the uri and set it in the class variable
            uriAsObservable().subscribe(retrievedUri => this.searchUri = retrievedUri);
        }
    }
```

If needed, the uri gets requested, if not, just use it. I know that this won't work that way, since the observables are async and `searchUri` would not be ready in time. But this is what I look for, is there a way, without bootstrapping and requesting all possible configurations at application-start?

As long as there aren't multiple layers of observables, they are great and easy.
But when a request might have certain preconditions or prerequisites, I don't know how to handle them.

What, if i need 3 or 5 parameter for my suggestion-request? Do I actually have to do something like (somewhat pseudo code) `getTertiaryParam1().subscribe(getNotSoInterestingParam2().subscribe(getParamofDoom3().subscribe(getUri().subscribe(getSuggestions(uri,p1,p2,p3,....,pN)))))`? Even when most of those params are constant when set once?

Another example I can not imagine would be how to combine such a request with an OAuth2 authentication required. What when my OAuth-interceptor figures, that my token is invalid, and I have to make a refreshToken-request beforehand, wait for the new token, and then send the actual suggestion-request with a valid Authorization? I would maybe check this beforehand, fix it if necessary, and then proceed.

If you haven't figured by now, I don't have a lot of experience in functional programming. I'm sure, throwing the right amount of flatMap and switchMaps on the issue will solve some the things, but as now, I'm stuck.

If you made it that far and maybe even understand what my questions are, thank you very much for your time!

Best regards, Manu

Answer (score 1):

You could cache the Uri with a ReplaySubject. Then it only gets queried once:

```
private uriCache: ReplaySubject<string>;
getSuggestions(searchTerm: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {
    return this.getSearchModuleUri()
        .switchMap(uri => this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(searchUri));
}

getSearchModuleUri(): Observable<string> {
    //still magical stuff - equal to Observable.of('http://host/api/foo')
    if(!this.uriCache){
        this.uriCache = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
        Observable
            .of('http://host/api/foo')
            .subscribe(uri => this.uriCache.next(uri));
    }
    return this.uriCache.asObservable();
}
```

Finally, you can use switchMap to map from source Observable to next Observable and return the resulting Observable.

When there are more than one parameter to get resolved before the request you could use Observable.zip, Observable.combineLatest or something like that to retrieve parameters and map to the final request.
Reactive programming is a key concept when working with javascript http calls.

Comment: I like the use of `ReplaySubject` for caching; but the rest of the code is basically his first example without an explanation as to why that can't change

Comment: That are the necessary steps to improve his code. Usage of a ReplaySubject and switchMap.

Comment: ReplaySubject is not the good solution here. APP_INITIALIZER is here for that. Also, subscribing from a service is a bad pratice that you should absolutely avoid.

Comment: @Maxime And what exactly would you subscribe to if you needed, for instance, push notifications from a webservice? Your view of the world seems to be awfully limited

Comment: My view of the world seems limited because I'm telling you not to subscribe to an observable from a service?  If you don't want to hear it, fine just keep subscribing. Otherwise, the whole point of observable is keep getting a stream of data so that you can react to it. If you subscribe from the service, how are you going to react to a new data from somewhere else?

Comment: @Maxime Yes; getting a stream *can* be the point; but I don't understand your point about the service. What about that makes it a poor data source? You can always add additional sources (I would imagine) but a service is just as capable of putting up a stream as anything else.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you're right to think that it might be a good idea to store your result within a class once, and then just access the cached result.

There's a dedicated token in Angular to help you do that: `APP_INITIALIZER`

It's supposed to be used not only by you (and you could also use many of them if you need to), that's why when using it, you should pass the `multi` property to `true`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    // your class holding the configuration
    AppConfig,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => config.loadConfig().toPromise(),
      deps: [AppConfig],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, you class holding the config should look like:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  private config: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public loadConfig(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .pipe(tap(config => (this.config = config)));
  }

  public getConfig() {
    return this.config;
  }
}
```

Now, before your app is bootsraped, it'll wait for the config to be loaded. Then you just inject the class and call `appConfig.getConfig` which is synchronous.

For the observables, never, never, never do the following:

```
getSuggestions: Observable<SearchResult[]>(searchTerm: string) {
  return this.getSearchModuleUri().subscribe(searchUri => this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(searchUri));
}
```

First, by subscribing to your stream, you do not return an Observable, you return a subscription. Typescript should throw an error.

If from the response of an Observable you need to trigger another one, use switchMap or flatMap:

```
getSuggestions: Observable<SearchResult[]>(searchTerm: string) {
  return this.getSearchModuleUri().pipe(
    flatMap(searchUri => this.http.get<SearchResult[]>(searchUri))
  )
}
```

Note that I didn't subscribe and that the consumer should be the one to subscribe.

Comment: APP_INITIALIZER is fine if you only need the result once (and I would imagine it also results in longer startup times). It does not solve the general problem of the messiness inherent in chained observables.

Comment: Application startup is depending on avaiability of a configuration maybe never used. That is bad practice.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET We do need the result only once, it's a config file right? We're not polling the config as far as I'm aware. OP said: I want to request the config once".

Comment: @David once more: OP said that he wants to wait for the config to be ready and fetch it only once. So yes it's going to be used and yes the app startup is dependening on availability of the config. It's the whole point.

Comment: What are you going to do later in the app? Put some "if config available" everywhere? It'll lead to write some unnecessary code everywhere in the app, subscribing to an observable from a service, dealing manually with the cache and all of that to still wait for a config to be available. It won't be faster, you'll not work with observable as you should (aka return stream and not subscribe to it from there), your code will become more complicated, harder to test, harder to read, harder to maintain and will lead to a non reactive app.

Comment: @Maxime
from The original question:
"without bootstrapping and requesting all possible configurations at application-start"

And in your opinion reactive programming leads to non reactive apps?

Comment: I don't see that sentence, and what's the context? Before the "without" ?

Comment: It starts with "is there a way", it's a question, not an affirmation. And from the sentence before, OP is looking from a way to use the config synchronously, which is what I'm doing here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167410/discussion-between-david-ibl-and-maxime).